# How to start SSH on a chroot Linux

Tags: android, linux, ssh, chroot

I managed to initiate Linux on my Android phone through the terminal and even start the SSH service and tested it using ConnectBot. However, this is a manual operation. I was thinking more of an automated way of doing this.

I used this Linux mechanism: http://mitchtech.net/android-backtrack-chroot/

My main issue I believe is that I'm trying to do some steps before and after `chroot` is done, which didn't seem to work on an Android app:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

//Mount the image
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("startbt");

//chroot into Linux
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bt");

//From inside chroot, start the ssh service
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/etc/init.d/ssh start");
```

This also did not seem to work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su & startbt & bt & /etc/init.d/ssh start");
```

I'm guessing again this is an issue what is interpreted as inside or outside the chroot. My main quest eventually is to start the SSH service automatically, not necessarily through an Android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

this will just launch `su` and then exit. The next exec won't be executed with elevated privileges. Likewise after executing `bt` the next command isn't executed within the chroot environment.

I presume `bt` is a script? You could change it to pass arguments to `chroot`, so you can pass it the command to execute, something like:

```
...
chroot new_root /etc/init.d/ssh start
...
```

To run this, you need to pass the command to `su` directly using the `-c` option. And you need to pass the commands as String array (or use a `ProcessBuilder`):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "startbt; bt"});
```

---

Another option would be to make `bt` pass arguments from the command line to chroot:

```
chroot new_root "$@"
```

and then pass them on the command line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "startbt; bt /etc/init.d/ssh start"});
```

Comment: Good point! I modified the `bt` script to have the command argument directly. However, when I did it through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, it didn't seem to work as I couldn't connect to it via SSH. On a side note, when I did it manually with the edited script, it worked fine. How can I troubleshoot this from the perspective of an Android app?

Comment: Are you sure your scripts can be found on the PATH? you may want to use the full path.

Comment: In the script it's `busybox chroot $mnt /bin/bash /etc/init.d/ssh start`, while on the Android app it's exactly as u specified.

Comment: They are in the path I believe. I access them from the terminal without having to do a `cd`. But I'll try the full path option.

Comment: Try passing the arguments as an array, I've updated my answer. And you may want to read the returned process' error/input stream to see if there's some error message.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to do things this way, I'd honestly just download an SSH server app.

I personally use **SSHDroid**.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid&hl=en

But from the looks of things you're building your own app to start the built-in ssh server yourself?  So you probably already know that you could already just do it using an app.

Good luck anyways.

Comment: He's trying to run an ssh server inside an alternative linux installation using chroot. That's something completely different then just running a ssh server on android.

Comment: The idea is that I want to create a class in which Linux starts up and another class to control it via SSH... All in autonomous fashion. So SSHDroid is not a solution since it needs user intervention. I apologize for not explaining this specifically at the beginning!